# How to reset ADB2C custom policy custom HTML cache?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom ADB2C policy that specifies `<ContentDefinition>` tags to use custom HTML. The custom HTML is stored in Azure Blob Storage.

The problem I have is that when I upload a new version of the custom HTML the changes don't show up when I go through the policy (unless I leave it overnight). I suspect that there might be some caching going on, but none of the documentation I have seen mentions caching.

Is there a way to disable/clear the cache, or might there be something else wrong that has similar symptoms?

The new files are definitely in the blob storage as I can request them directly in a browser and get the latest versions.

I can also upload the new html files with new names and tweak the policy to point to the new names, so I'm fairly confident I'm not making a silly configuration mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAD B2C does not cache or download your HTML file. AAD B2C drops JS to tell the *client* to download the HTML, then client side JS that AAD B2C delivered, will have the *client* merge the HTML file with the content on the page. The problem here is to do with the **client** browser caching the HTML file. You can prove this by using Incognito/Private mode usually.

You can see more info here on how this process works:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#custom-html-and-css-overview

Comment: I thought I'd tried a hard browser refresh, but clearly not at the right time!

Comment: @Jas-suri-msft  is there any way to configure the caching headers (etag/expires) on the content AAD B2C delivers?

Comment: No, and in this case, it’s not content AAD B2C delivered. You could add it to your HTML endpoint. Content delivered by AAD B2C should not be cached for more than a few minutes by default.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT There must be some sort of caching happening somewhere.. I've just turned off the option to use a custom template, downloaded a new browser, opened it in private browser mode, ran the user flow and it still shows my old - not updated - template on the b2c login. Hard refresh does nothing. Please advise, this is making it very difficult to develop on and use in production.